# How can I implement AJAX to remove an entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to remove an entry from my Rails app using AJAX. I'm new to AJAX and I'm a little bit stuck because of two things.

1. I don't think if my url field is correct. I grab a specific entry using $this from jquery but I am not sure as to whether I use "this" for task_path(variable). I need to pass a specific task for deletion but is this the correct way to implement this?
2. I didn't use anything that required .currentTarget(); Usually in all the AJAX examples I've seen, .currentTarget() was used to grab info from a form and then was manipulated in the .ajax call. I don't have a form. Do I need to implement .currentTarget for the delete action?

Here is my ajax.js file:

```
$(function() {
$(this).on('delete', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: task_path(@task),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).remove();
    },
  });
 });
});

def destroy
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!"}
  format.json { render root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!" }
  end
end
```

This has really been racking my brain. Thanks for any help.

---------------EDIT----------------

I've tried to do the recommended changes and I've come up with this set of code. I think that I'm getting close but I'm not quite there yet.

```
$(function() {
$(this).on('delete', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var id = $(this).attr("href");
var data_info = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: id + "destroy",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data_info,
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).remove();
    },
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store `id` in `data-` attribute, not in `href`. For example you could have `data-id=<%= task.id %>` (assuming you are using `erb`). Then get that `id` and use it in your `js` file.

And for the `url`, you can use [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes/), which gives you Rails routes in Javascript. So, your Javascript would be something ike this:

```
$(function() {
    $(this).on('delete', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var data_info = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: Routes.task_path(id),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data_info,
      success: function(response) {
        $(this).remove();
      },
    });
  });
});
```

This should give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks Ako. I appreciate the help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing client-side and server-side logic in your `url` field.  If I understand your situation, you're trying to run that .js file with `url: task_path(@task)`.  Since that file lives in the browser, it has no idea how to translate `task_path` into an actual path.  You'll need to either

1. Use the actual path ('/tasks/$(this.id)/destroy') with some means of getting of correct id for the URL (could do with data-attributes in the HTML, for instance).
2. Convert the file to a .js.haml file and render/serve it when you need it.  This is not considered best practice.

Other than that, the ajax call looks like the correct jQuery.

Comment: Hey @ABMagil, thanks for the reply, could you take a look at my edit? Is this close to what I'm trying to get. How can I take a look at what my variables are? I tried using debugger; but it doesn't seem to stop.

Comment: That really depends on what you're clicking.  My suggestion would be take a look in Chrome Dev Tools- Right Click on whatever you're clicking to cause the AJAX action and use "Inspect Element" to see what the attributes are on the link/button/whatever element you're clicking.

Look at this fiddle with Dev Tools and you'll see I added a data-attribute to the buttons.  When you click them, you can use that data-attribute to control the "url" field in the AJAX request.
http://jsfiddle.net/9zCGZ/1/